# Convert a MySQL statement containing where, group by, sum and having to Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I am trying to convert the following MySql to Linq to Sql (with or without Lambda experessions)

select * from table  where table.column2 < '2014-11-27 00:00:00' group by table.column1 having sum(table.column3 = 0) > sum(table.column3 = 1)

Is it possible and if so any pointers?

Column1 is a string,
Column2 is a DateTime, 
Column3 is a TinyInt (Boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IQueryable<MyType> query = // get table IQueryable from the Linq2Sql data context

var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-11-27");
var result = query.Where(t => t.Column2 < dateTime)
    .GroupBy(t => t.Column1)
    // Linq doesn't have HAVING, you can just use Where(). Here, we're operating on
    // an IQueryable of IGrouping, and we're filtering based on taking sums over the groups
    .Where(g => g.Sum(t => !t.Column3 ? 1 : 0) > g.Sum(t => t.Column3 ? 1 : 0))
    // it's not clear to me what you want here. Without any Select, each full grouping will get
    // pulled into memory as an IGrouping. If instead you just want the Column1 values, you'd
    // want .Select(g => g.Key)
    .Select(...);
```

Note I'm assuming here that you've mapped Column3 to a bool in your entity classes. If you instead have it as a byte, then you'll have to do `t.Column3 == 0` instead of `!t.Column3`.

Comment: Column3 is an Enumerator in the entity which is stopping the above from working

Comment: @HarryParker What type is Column3 in the database? Can you add your database table schema and Linq2Sql Entity class to your post?